# formulario: grafica de java/ corre perfecto cuando lo compilo desde javac por cmd, pero desde netbeans no?

Tags: netbeans, compilacion

**tome el codigo de un ejemplo al pasarlo por el javac desde el cmd el codigo se ejecuta bien.
cuando lo escribo en el netbeans me da error (no me toma el nombre de la clase) pero son identicos , no logro entender porque no compila desde neatbens.**
**Agrego la imagen del codigo, solo esa parte me da error, es el nombre de la clase.**
** el codigo es simplemente un Un text area con scroll**
** a continuacion esta el codigo que funciona y luego el que no funciona en netbeans**

** al colocar el cursor el error en la linea 6 dice "Formulario8 is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener" **

[image: es la imagen del principio del ejercicio que llame, Fromulario8]

```
//este corre:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Formulario extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 
 private JTextField textfield1;
 private JScrollPane scrollpane1;
 private JTextArea textarea1;
 private JButton boton1,botonC;

 String texto = "";

 public Formulario(){
  setLayout(null);
  textfield1 = new JTextField();
  textfield1.setBounds(10,10,200,30);
  add(textfield1);

  boton1 = new JButton("Agregar");
  boton1.setBounds(250,10,100,30);
  add(boton1);
  boton1.addActionListener(this);

  botonC = new JButton("Cerrar");
  botonC.setBounds(350,10,100,30);
  add(botonC);
  botonC.addActionListener(this);

  textarea1 = new JTextArea();
  scrollpane1 = new JScrollPane(textarea1);
  scrollpane1.setBounds(10,50,400,300);
  add(scrollpane1);
 }
// eventos

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.getSource() == boton1){
    texto += textfield1.getText() + "\n";
    textarea1.setText(texto);
    textfield1.setText("");
  }
  if (e.getSource() == botonC){
     System.exit(0); // es el boton cerrar
  }

 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  Formulario formulario1 = new Formulario();
  formulario1.setBounds(0,0,540,400);
  formulario1.setVisible(true);
  formulario1.setResizable(false);
  formulario1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 }
}


//*******************************************************************
// este no corre, es similar en netbeans ****************************
   package formulario8;

import javax.swing.*;  // para la interfaz grafica
import java.awt.event.*;   // controla los eventos

public class Formulario8 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   //elementos
    private JTextField texto1;
    private JScrollPane scroll1;
    private JTextArea area1;
    private JButton boton1, botonC;
    
    String texto =""; // guarda el texto temporalmente
    
  // constructor
    public Formulario8(){
        setLayout(null);
        texto1 = new JTextField();
        texto1.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 30);
        add(texto1);
        
        boton1 = new JButton("Agregar");
        boton1.setBounds(250, 10, 100, 30);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);
        add(boton1);
        
        botonC = new JButton("Cerrar");
        botonC.setBounds(320, 10, 100, 30);
        botonC.addActionListener(this);
        add(botonC);
        
        area1 = new JTextArea();
        scroll1 = new JScrollPane(area1);
        scroll1.setBounds(10, 50, 400, 300);
        add(scroll1);
   }
    // eventos
     public void actionPermormed(ActionEvent e){
         if(e.getSource() == boton1){
            texto += texto1.getText() + "\n";
            area1.setText(texto);
            texto1.setText("");
         }
          if (e.getSource() == botonC){
           System.exit(0); // es el boton cerrar
         }
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Formulario8 formulario = new Formulario8();
       formulario.setBounds(0, 0, 540, 400);
       formulario.setVisible(true);
       formulario.setResizable(false);
       formulario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Mira bien el nombre del método... hay una anotación, @Overrides, que te habría ayudado a detectar el problema.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76, entiendo parcialmente, creo que aun me falta entrar mas en el codigo